# How do I fix a loose joint between the top and bottom of the digger base?

Tags: duplo, repair

[image: digger base]

How do I repair a loose-fitting joint between the top and bottom of the Duplo digger base? It has been used for only about a year. Is the wear more likely on the top or the bottom piece?

Comment: FYI: The two parts are likely [this turntable base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92005#T=C) and [this modified plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25548#T=C&C=85).